# dhtmlx calendar hidden by dhtmlx grid

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I've got a problem whereby a dhtmlxCalendarObject  is being hidden by a dhtmlXGridObject. 
To create the dhtmlxCalendarObject I create a div and dhtmlxCalendarObject like this:

```
<div id="calendar1" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:22px;"></div>
```

... then later:

```
var cal1 = new dhtmlxCalendarObject('calendar1', true, {isYearEditable: true, isMonthEditable: true});
```

Under the dhtmlxCalendarObject I have a dhtmlXGridObject created like this:

```
<div id="gridalarmsbox" style="width:99%; border:1px solid #000000"></div>
```

... then later:

```
var gridalarms = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridalarmsbox');
```

When I click on the calendar, half of it is hidden behind the grid, how could I resolve this?

I have tried using z-index in the above divs like this:

```
<div id="gridalarmsbox" style="width:99%; border:1px solid #000000; z-index:-1;"></div>
```

and

```
<div id="calendar1" style="position:absolute; z-index:-999; left:0px; top:22px;"></div>
```

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is happening in Internet Explorer 11.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue cannot be reproduced locally.
If the problem still occurs for you could you, please provide a complete demo, where the problem can be reconstructed (you may contact support@dhtmlx.com with the link to this question).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var cal1 = new dhtmlxCalendarObject('calendar1', true, {isYearEditable: true, isMonthEditable: true});
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
                cal1.parent.style.zIndex = 200;
            }
```